# VS2022 Kestrel Self signed certificate with DNS IP Address

Tags: .net, blazor, certificate, kestrel

The goal is that I can launch my .Net Blazor Server application from the VS2022 (Kestrel) with the IP address of my developer machine (so not with 127.0.0.1 or localhost) but my effective machine IP (172.23.110.47) and I can have a correct HTTPS connection while doing so.
I have run the following in Powershell

```
PS C:\windows\system32> New-SelfSignedCertificate -Subject "localhost" -TextExtension @("2.5.29.17={text}DNS=localhost&IPAddress=127.0.0.1&IPAddress=::1&IPAddress=172.23.110.47")
   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\MY

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
53E7417A264B229B4F52638B15433F7C09476224  CN=localhost


PS C:\windows\system32> $mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "ControlTech" -Force -AsPlainText
PS C:\windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -Path cert:\localMachine\my\53E7417A264B229B4F52638B15433F7C09476224 | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\temp\MyJpfCertificate.pfx -Password $mypwd


    Verzeichnis: C:\temp


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        21.03.2023     09:05           2685 MyJpfCertificate.pfx


PS C:\windows\system32> dotnet dev-certs https --clean --import C:\Temp\MyJpfCertificate.pfx -p ControlTech
Cleaning HTTPS development certificates from the machine. A prompt might get displayed to confirm the removal of some of the certificates.
HTTPS development certificates successfully removed from the machine.
The certificate at 'C:\Temp\MyJpfCertificate.pfx' is not a valid ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.
```

I can't find a solution to the error The certificate at 'C:\Temp\MyJpfCertificate.pfx' is not a valid ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.  Where do I miss something?

Comment: Am I trying to do something pointless here or is there effectively no solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
$params = @{
    Subject           = 'CN=172.23.110.47'
    FriendlyName      = 'Local HTTPS development certificate'
    TextExtension     = @('2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1',  # SSLServerAuthentication
                          '2.5.29.17={text}ipaddress=172.23.110.47')
    NotAfter          = (Get-Date).AddDays(397)                 # Max TLS validity period
    CertStoreLocation = 'Cert:\LocalMachine\My'
}
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @params
```

The certificate will have an EKU extension with the Server Authentication OID and will not have 'localhost' in the DnsNameList.